# Управился или справился с делами?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно говорить: управился или справился с делами?

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта корректны.

> **Управиться**, (с чем). Кончить какую-л. работу или хлопоты; справиться с чем-л. **У. с работой.** У. со стиркой. У. по дому, по хозяйству.
>
> ***СПРАВИТЬСЯ, -влюсь, -вишься; св***. 1. обычно с чем. Сделать, выполнить что-л.; суметь сделать, выполнить что-л. **С. с работой. С. с поручением.** С. с задачей. С. с платежами. // Нар.-разг. Сделать всю нужную работу где-л. С. по дому. Справлюсь на (в) огороде и зайду к тебе.

Answer (score 1):

Есть стилистическое различие: "справиться" - нейтральное, "управиться" - разговорное.